# Two date parameters while connecting Google Data Studio with BigQuery

Tags: looker-studio

As I read in [this link](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9002005) "Report viewers can't modify data source parameters directly. However, if you've enabled date parameters for a BigQuery data source, and your report includes a date range control, viewers can use that control to request different starting and ending dates from the BigQuery data."

I'm facing a situation where I need to filter two periods at the same time and over the same data source:

- Period where users installed my app.
- Period where users made actions.

For now, Data Studio permits only one date parameter in customized queries for BigQuery (DS_START_DATE, DS_END_DATE). But what if I need an additional date parameter? Is there a solution to this need?

Answer (score -1):

Include all the data from BigQuery to Data Studio first, then set custom date range for the specific charts/tables.

Comment: I need the two dates as inputs to the query, not as output fields to filter over in Data Studio side

Comment: @alek6dj Where you able to solve this problem ?